# Flashing cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have got a bit of code where when a cell is of a certain value it changes its interior to red and its font to white. what i want to do is to make the colour of the text alternate between white and red every second as long as the cells interior is red (once it turns red it will remain red).
i want the user to have the impression that the cell is actually flashing.

i wrote this code:

```
For r = 6 To 1000
    With .Cells(r, 6)
        While .Interior.Color = RGB(237, 67, 55)
            .Font.Color = RGB(237, 67, 55)
             Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            .Font.Color = vbWhite
        Wend
    End With
Next r
```

excel just makes the first cell that has red interior "flash" ones and then crashes. the red cells are not in consecutive order.

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193220.aspx) you can probably tweak it a bit to meet your needs, as it worked for me pasting this into a new module.

Comment: http://excel.tips.net/T002134_Flashing_Cells.html

Comment: You could have conditional formats where the conditions depends both on the value of the cell and the value of a hidden fixed cell (or perhaps even a named value). Just toggle the value of this fixed cell once a second, and let conditional formatting do its magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a go with:

```
Sub Flash_Ahhh()

Dim strRange As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim iFlasher As Integer

lngCounter = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row    'Find last row of data
lngCol = ActiveCell.Column                                          ' Find the active column

vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = vArr(0)                                                'The Active Column Letter

strRange = Col_Letter & "6:" & Col_Letter & lngCounter              'The range of all cells in the active column



    For Each rCell In Range(strRange).Cells


            Select Case rCell.Interior.Color

                Case Is = vbRed

                    For iFlasher = 1 To 10

                        If rCell.Font.Color = vbRed Then
                            rCell.Font.Color = vbWhite
                            Else
                            rCell.Font.Color = vbRed
                        End If

                        Call WaitFor(0.1)


                    Next iFlasher
                    rCell.Font.Color = vbWhite

                Case Else

            End Select



    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Use the following to cause the time delay:

```
Sub WaitFor(NumOfSeconds As Single)
    Dim SngSec As Single
    SngSec = Timer + NumOfSeconds

    Do While Timer < SngSec
        DoEvents
   Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not `Call WaitFor(1)` for a one second flash ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent It's a trade off between the loop and the delay. You can fiddle with the numbers to change "flashiness" and length of flash. You'd probably also want to do a `rCell.Select` to jump down the column if you're going from 6:1000

Comment: Okay .................I upvoted because I think `WaitFor()` is pretty cool.